# Changed the default login screen in react-admin still shows the the old login form

Tags: react-admin

I have followed the directions in this location to change the default login page: https://github.com/marmelab/ra-example-oauth/tree/master/app

This involves creating a new page and modifying the app code as per the below:

```html
return (
        <Admin
            title=""
            dataProvider={dataProvider}
            customReducers={{ theme: themeReducer }}
            customRoutes={customRoutes}
            layout={Layout}
            loginPage={LoginPage}
            i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
            authProvider={authProvider}
        // theme={myTheme}
        >
            <Resource name="clients" {...clients} />
            <Resource name="referrals" {...referrals} />
            <Resource name="documents" {...documents} />
        </Admin>
    );
```

And in the referenced login page I have extended the react-admin login page with the new login form as per below:

```html
import React from 'react';
import { Login } from 'react-admin';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';

const LoginPage = (props) => <Login {...props} loginForm={<LoginForm />} />;

export default LoginPage;
```

But even after deleting the old login page/form I still get the old login page on logout with username and password.

Is there soemething else in the documentation that I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

I have found the issue, the extension method is no longer correct in the example:

I have changed:

```html
const LoginPage = (props) => <Login {...props} loginForm={<LoginForm />} />;
```

To:

```html
const LoginPage = (props) => (
    <Login {...props} >
        <LoginForm />
    </Login>
);
```

Comment: Could you edit your original post and delete this one please ?